# Redis Benchmarking from java

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I'm trying to compare the performance of NoSql databases Redis,Cassandra and MongoDB.
i'm using jedis in java to create and read records.Now I'm inserting 10 Million records and use java System.currentTimeMillis() to get the time before and after read/write to get the time taken.Is there any other methods to get the exact time taken for these operations ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use YSCB for performance benchmarks for various NoSQLs.

A few helpful links  :

- http://www.datastax.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/WP-Benchmarking-Top-NoSQL-Databases.pdf
- https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/